# Byte to byte encryption "C" program logical mistakes

Tags: c, debugging, byte

Good day! I have this software made to encrypt and decrypt files. I am new to Real Time Operating Systems as I normally program microcontrollers, I was programming the basic things in Operatins Systems some time ago, including this project. The Codeblocks gnu C portable compiler IDE tells me there are no errors only warnings. But when I execute the code it runs to some point and then gives the error that the program stopped unexpectedly and the command prompt needs to close.

The code and warnings are here. From the command prompt I get: `Process returned 255 0xFF`. Maybe a variable definition needs to be more than 8-bits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main ()
{
    char *f1;
    char *f2;

    printf ("Please enter file for encryption\n");
    scanf  ("%s", f1);
    printf ("Please enter the name of the file after encryption\n");
    scanf  ("%s", f2);

    Encrypt(f1, f2);
}

int Encrypt(char * FILENAME, char * NEW_FILENAME)
{                                  /********VARIABLE DEFINITION BLOCK*******/
         printf("Encryption started\n");
         FILE *inFile;                                       //Declare inFile
         FILE *outFile;                                      //Declare outFile
         char *key;
         char *process;

         char Byte;
         char newByte;
         /*int  n;*/

                                    /******USER INPUT BLOCK*******/
         printf ("Please enter 'encryption or decryption'\n");
         scanf  ("%s", process);
         printf ("Please enter the key\n");
         scanf  ("%s", key);
         printf("Opening files\n");

         /*int i=0;*/
                                    /******FILE OPEN BLOCK********/
         inFile = fopen(FILENAME,"rb");
         outFile = fopen(NEW_FILENAME, "w");

                                    /*****MAIN PROGRAM BLOCK******/
         if(inFile == NULL)                     /* check if the input file is empy */
         {
            printf("Error: Can't Open inFile\n");
         }

                                                /* check if the output file is empty */
         if(outFile == NULL)
         {
            printf("Error: Can't open outFile\n");
         }
                                                /* if both files are not empty output "Encrypting" and begin encryption */
         else
         {
                 printf("File Opened, Encrypting\n");
                                                /* encrypting cycle */
                 while(1)
                 {
                         printf(".");                /* loading symbol */

                                                     /* if the current byte is not the "End of file" byte and the process is encryption */
                         if(Byte!=EOF && process == 1)
                         {                          /* Byte = function get char from "inFile" */
                                 Byte = fgetc (inFile);
                         //      printf("%d",Byte); /* the new byte = old byte plus 1 byte from the key */
                                 newByte = Byte + key;
                                                    /* we put the new byte in the new already encrypted file */
                                 fputc(newByte, outFile);

                         }
                                                    /* if the current file is not the "End of file" byte and the process is decryption */
                         if(Byte!=EOF && process == 2)
                         {                          /* we read 1 byte with the function get char from the file recorded in the string (pointer) "inFile */
                                 Byte = fgetc (inFile);
                         //      printf("%d",Byte); /* 1 new byte, equals the old byte plus 1 byte from the key */
                                 newByte = Byte + key;
                                                    /* we put the new byte with the function put char in the string (pointer) in which the output file is */
                                 fputc(newByte, outFile);

                         }
                                                    /* if the two "while conditions" are not true we print "End of file" */
                         else
                         {
                                 printf("End of File\n");
                         }
                    return 1;
                 }
         }
}
```

Build output:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Encryption-software (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\arakel-the-dragon\Documents\Encryption-software\main.c|7|warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain]|
C:\Users\arakel-the-dragon\Documents\Encryption-software\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\arakel-the-dragon\Documents\Encryption-software\main.c|17|warning: implicit declaration of function 'Encrypt' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
C:\Users\arakel-the-dragon\Documents\Encryption-software\main.c||In function 'Encrypt':|
C:\Users\arakel-the-dragon\Documents\Encryption-software\main.c|65|warning: comparison between pointer and integer|
C:\Users\arakel-the-dragon\Documents\Encryption-software\main.c|69|warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast|
C:\Users\arakel-the-dragon\Documents\Encryption-software\main.c|75|warning: comparison between pointer and integer|
C:\Users\arakel-the-dragon\Documents\Encryption-software\main.c|79|warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast|
C:\Users\arakel-the-dragon\Documents\Encryption-software\main.c|92|warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|
C:\Users\arakel-the-dragon\Documents\Encryption-software\main.c|34|warning: 'process' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
C:\Users\arakel-the-dragon\Documents\Encryption-software\main.c|36|warning: 'key' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
C:\Users\arakel-the-dragon\Documents\Encryption-software\main.c|65|warning: 'Byte' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]|
C:\Users\arakel-the-dragon\Documents\Encryption-software\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\arakel-the-dragon\Documents\Encryption-software\main.c|13|warning: 'f1' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
C:\Users\arakel-the-dragon\Documents\Encryption-software\main.c|15|warning: 'f2' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 12 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Warnings are there for a reason.  Don't ignore them.

Comment: Processes only return a single byte when the call exit(). So a return code of 255 likely means that the process returned -1, and it got truncated to 8 bits. You do not need ot change a variable size to fix this.

Comment: This is not "encryption" - you're simply adding an offset (`key`) to a byte value - except you're doing that incorrectly because you're not dereferencing `key`, but using the raw pointer value.

Comment: @Dai It's a Caesar cipher, the simplest form of encryption known.

Comment: I believe @chux means you *must* pass initialised pointers to `scanf` which also point to enough allocated memory, which you are not doing.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oops I wrote my comment without the important "un-". So the corrected comment should be: `char *f1;... scanf ("%s", f1);`  --> Code is passing un-initialized `f1` to `scanf()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's address the warnings.

Several of the warnings are for using uninitialized variables.  Each of these involves passing a `char *` to `scanf`.  The `%s` format specifier to `scanf` expects a pointer to a character array.  What you've passed in instead is a pointer that isn't pointing anywhere.  Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as a crash.

Declare these variables as `char` arrays with enough space for the input you expect.  Also, add a length specifier to `%s` specifying the maximum number of characters to read.

The integer/pointer comparison errors are because of how you're using `process`.  This variable is a `char *`, expected to point to a null terminated string, but you're comparing it against an integer which doesn't make sense.

Instead, use the `strcmp` function to compare it against `"encryption"` or `"decryption"`.

The "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" is because you're trying to add `key`, which is a `char *`, to `Byte`, which is a `char`.  You  presumably want to index `key` to get a particular character from it, i.e. `key[1]`.  You'll also want a separate counter for the current key index, and you'll want to reset it to 0 when it becomes greater than or equal to the length of the key.

The first time into your `while` loop, `Byte` hasn't been set, but you still compare it against `EOF`.  You also overwrite the value of `Byte` you're comparing when you read in the next byte, but then you don't check if that is `EOF`.

You need to change the type of `Byte` and `newByte` to `int`, since that's what `fgetc` returns.  The `EOF` value is typically outside the range of a `char`, so you'll never find it unless you change the type.  You should also perform the read and comparison as part of the loop condition instead of using `while(1)` and remove the read from the loop body.

The implicit declaration warning is because you call the `Encrypt` function before defining or declaring it.  As a result, an implicit declaration of `int Encrypt()` (i.e. a function taking an unknown number of arguments and returning an `int`) is created.  This happens to coincide which how it is defined, but still not a match.

Either add a declaration for this function before `main`, or move the whole function before `main`.

Besides the warnings, the `return 1` statement executes at the bottom of your `while` loop, so the loop only goes though one iteration before exiting.  The above suggestion to test the value of `Byte` in the condition should address this.

Your decrypt is currently doing the same as your encrypt.  You probably want to subtract here instead of add.  In both cases, you also need to check for wraparound.  So if the encrypted value is larger than 255, subtract 256.  Similarly for the decrypt, if the value is less than 0, add 256.

After applying these fixes, your code should look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// declare function before it's called
void Encrypt(char * FILENAME, char * NEW_FILENAME);

int main ()
{
    char f1[100];   // array big enough to hold expected input
    char f2[100];   // array big enough to hold expected input

    printf ("Please enter file for encryption\n");
    scanf  ("%99s", f1);    // set max characters to read to prevent buffer overflow
    printf ("Please enter the name of the file after encryption\n");
    scanf  ("%99s", f2);

    Encrypt(f1, f2);
    return 0;
}

void Encrypt(char * FILENAME, char * NEW_FILENAME)
{
         printf("Encryption started\n");
         FILE *inFile;
         FILE *outFile;
         char key[50];         // array big enough to hold expected input
         char process[50];     // array big enough to hold expected input
         int keylen, keyidx;

         int Byte;       // fgetc returns int, so use an int
         int newByte;

         printf ("Please enter 'encryption or decryption'\n");
         scanf  ("%49s", process);
         printf ("Please enter the key\n");
         scanf  ("%49s", key);
         keylen = strlen(key);
         keyidx = 0;    // starting index into key
         printf("Opening files\n");

         inFile = fopen(FILENAME,"rb");
         outFile = fopen(NEW_FILENAME, "w");

         if(inFile == NULL)
         {
            printf("Error: Can't Open inFile\n");
         }
         else if(outFile == NULL)
         {
            printf("Error: Can't open outFile\n");
         }
         else
         {
                 printf("File Opened, Encrypting\n");
                 while((Byte = fgetc(inFile)) != EOF)    // read a byte, check if EOF
                 {
                         if (!strcmp(process,"encryption"))
                         {
                                 newByte = Byte + key[keyidx];    // use key index
                                 if (newByte > 255) newByte -= 256;   // check for overflow
                         }
                         else if (!strcmp(process,"decryption"))
                         {
                                 newByte = Byte - key[keyidx];
                                 if (newByte < 0) newByte += 256;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                            newByte = Byte;
                         }
                         fputc(newByte, outFile);
                         keyidx++;
                         // loop to the start of the key if needed
                         if (keyidx >= keylen) keyidx = 0;
                 }
         }
         if (inFile != null) fclose(inFile);     // close your files when you're done
         if (outFile != null) fclose(outFile);
}
```

Comment: It will take time to go through all of this. Normally I dont pay attention to warnings, since they are ignored depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Ok, it works! Thank you very much, Now I have to check all of your post and learn every problem, piece by piece. I think this is a simple byte to byte encryption software? If the key is longer, than the security becomes higher?

Comment: I thank you for the help. It was useful. I have details like this to pay attention to. Can you give me a good tutorial, so I can begin learning the procedure? If you need help with microcontrollers, tell me.